What's the best way to separate out the card?

I have an ecommerce type solution where on the index.cs I do have
my models and retrieving data from database, on the index.cshtml.

I do some futher data manipulation with joining tables to get top
sold , newly added etc...


In a foreach loop I show the products in some nice layout.  Works great. However now I want to sprinkle in different prodcard types inside that loop to break up a monotone look.

So I would like to break out the prodcard into its own .cshtml.

However with all the objects and logic on the index.cshtml page it will be loads of work to turn this into a razor component or a partial as I would need to pass much into these.
In PHP this would be easy.
Is there any other widget where I could simply do:
foreach(var prod in products)
{include prodcard.cshtml} 
if(prod.special=true){{include prodcard2.cshtml} 
}

where it has access to all parent level variables and objects?
Some Actual Code:
 foreach (var w4 in ofstatus4)
{
ctaCards = GlobalHelp.GetCTAText(w4.Type);
double storeCoupon, itemRate, salePrice = 0;

string zip, lat, lng;
(string, string) exLink;
exLink.Item1 = "";
exLink.Item2 = "";
string itemPicUrl = "/IM/*/" + w4.EMID.ToString() + "/" + Model.Referrer;
string browserTarget = "_self";

if (w4.Type == 4) //Linkout
{
    exLink = GlobalHelp.GetExternalLinkCTA(w4.OFID, w4.Type, Model._context);
    itemPicUrl = exLink.Item2;
    browserTarget = "_blank";
}
if (w4.Zip == null) { zip = "00000"; } else { zip = w4.Zip; }
if (w4.Latitude == null) { lat = "0.0"; } else { lat = w4.Latitude; }
if (w4.Longitude == null) { lng = "0.0"; } else { lng = w4.Longitude; }
string link = "";
//STORE SALE CHECK
if (w4.StorewideSale > 0)
{
    itemRate = (double)w4.Rate;
    storeCoupon = ((double)w4.StorewideSale / 100) * itemRate;
    salePrice = itemRate - storeCoupon;

}
else { salePrice = (double)w4.Rate; }


var search_params = w4.Zip + " " + w4.OfferingName + " " + w4.OfferingDescription + " " + w4.OfferingDetails + " " + w4.ClassInstructor + " " + w4.Specialty + " " + w4.OfferingCategory + " " + w4.Tags;

    var score = await GlobalHelp.GetSurveyScore(0, w4.OFID, Model._context);

        <div class="prod_list">

            
                @if (w4.Type != 4)
        {
            link = "location.href = '" + @itemPicUrl + "';";
        }
        else
        {
            link = "window.open('" + @itemPicUrl + "','_newtab');";
           
        }
            <div class="card" data-id="w4.OfferingCategory" style="padding:3px;" onclick="@link">
         <div class="con-star">
                    <h7 data-id="@search_params"></h7>
                </div>
            
                    <div class="con-image">
                    @{
                         <img src="https://@Model.Platform.AzureStorageName/offerings/@w4.OFID/of_hero.png" loading="lazy" class="image" data-alt-src="https://@Model.Platform.AzureStorageName/sellers/@w4.SPID/spprofile.png,https://@Model.Platform.AzureStorageName/marketoperators/@Model.MarketOperator.MOID/mo_logo.png" onerror="loadAltImage(this);" />
                    }
                    
                </div>
                @{
                            <!--@Convert.ToDouble(score.avgScore)-->
                Random random = new Random();
                double rating =  random.Next(4,6);
                int ratingcnt = 0;
                if (rating > 0.0 )
                {
                    ratingcnt = random.Next(5, 20);
                }

                if (Model.MarketOperator.MOID == 147 || Model.MarketOperator.MOID == 155 || Model.MarketOperator.MOID == 168 || Model.MarketOperator.MOID == 172)
                {} else
                {

                <div class="row gt-0 p-0 g-0" style="padding:0;margin:0,0;"><div id="rateYo-@w4.OFID" class="col-6 rateyo rateYo-@w4.OFID g-0 p-0" style="margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px" data-score="@Convert.ToDouble(score.avgScore)"></div><div class="col-6 g-0 p-0" style="font-size: .8rem;margin-top:0; font-color:green;"><font color="green">@score.totalReview</font></div></div>
                }
                    }


                    

            <div class="con-text">

                                                                    
                    <h6 data-id="@zip" data-id1="@lat" data-id2="@lng" data-id3="@w4.OfferingCategory.ToUpper()">
                    @w4.OfferingCategory
                </h6>
            </div>


Design your prodcard and prodcard2 partials, and set the model type at the top of each file:
@model [whatever type "prod" is]
Then in your Index.cshtml:
@foreach(var prod in products) 
{
    if(!prod.special)
    {
        <partial name="prodcard" model="prod" />
    }
    else
    {
        <partial name="prodcard2" model="prod" />
    }
}


Yea I know its doable this way,  there is just do much business logic on the parent .cshtml itself it will be a nightmare to move it and duplicate it over several partials.  I'll just have to use html sections to make it readable and keep it all in the parent.  This is what happens when you inherit someone else's code.  Yours however is the correct answer
